# Where in the movie Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2 is the answer to who created Rocket Raccoon hidden?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

According to the tweet below by James Gunn, the answer to who created Rocket Raccoon in the MCU is hidden somewhere in Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2.

[image]

Which Easter eggs is James Gunn referring to?

**Edit 1**: While [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/215559/109861) to the question [*Who created Rocket in the MCU?*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175373/who-created-rocket-in-the-mcu) does provide an anagram as a candidate for the Easter egg, and given that each movie in the GOTG franchise is known for being a treasure trove of Easter eggs, the objective of this question is to inquire if there are other such candidates, and if any of them are more conclusive.

**Edit 2**: Since [Gunn was considering making Annihilus the creator of Rocket and the ultimate antagonist of GOTG Vol. 3 instead of High Evolutionary at one point](https://www.cinemablend.com/superheroes/marvel-cinematic-universe/james-gunn-confirms-alternate-villain-he-considered-for-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-3) and also since [Gunn had already expressed interest in wanting to play around with Annihilus in the GOTG film franchise as early as 2016](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Guardians-Galaxy-James-Gunn-Wants-Two-Fantastic-Four-Characters-Franchise-125237.html), it's possible that the Easter eggs that Gunn is referring to in the tweet are dedicated to Annihilus as opposed to High Evolutionary.

Comment: Potentially this: https://comicbook.com/marvel/amp/news/guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-rocket-creator-easter-egg/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who created Rocket in the MCU?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175373/who-created-rocket-in-the-mcu)

Comment: @Clockwork, while one of the answers in the question just provides an anagram as a candidate for the Easter egg in question, I am wondering if there are more fitting candidates for it in the movie.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot, given that the Reddit post mentioned therein provides multiple pieces of evidence that all converge to the same answer and it's the most comprehensive take on this question that I've seen thus far, I'd have accepted it as the answer for the time being.

Comment: I retracted my vote. The questions are similar but the answers are not satisfying. I don't know what would be the correct course of action in that scenario.

Comment: Given that Gunn was debating having an entirely different villain, I'm guess that this is much like the whole '*who is Snoke? Who is Rey's father?'* situation, where they were just making it up as they went.

Comment: @Valorum, since it was always between High Evolutionary and Annihilus according to Gunn, and since Gunn had already expressed interest in wanting to play around with Annihilus in the GOTG film franchise as early as '16, an Annihilus Easter egg in GOTG Vol 2 would be an incredible find! 
Moreover, in the tweet above, dated 30 Nov '17, Gunn himself stated that the answer to who created Rocket is hidden somewhere in GOTG Vol 2. This lends credence to the prospect of there actually being Easter eggs dedicated to whoever Gunn was going for as being the creator of Rocket while directing GOTG Vol 2.

Comment: @SatyajitSen - Or he could just be full of shit and trying to bait the audience

Comment: @Valorum, that's not impossible, yes. 